# Load XML file to server

Tags: php

I have a simple php application that uses, among others, an hourly updated external XML file.
I need to use only one of the file's fields, thus, I used `simplexml_load_file()`.
The problem is that this function only works with files currently saved on the server and not external ones.

How can I download the XML file periodically on the server (a download on every refresh would work too)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
copy('http://www.example.com/', 'local-file.xml');
?>
```

[copy](http://php.net/copy) can do this in a memory-light manner (it doesn't need to load the entire file into memory like for example file_get_contents).

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents('updated.xml',
                  file_get_contents('http://someulr.com/updated.xml')
                 );

simplexml_load_file('updated.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it may help you

```
<?php

function getXML()
{   

    // initialize the XML Parser
    $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
    // Set the functions to handle opening and closing tags 
    xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startElementHandler", "endElementHandler"); 

    // Set the function to handle blocks of character data 
    xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "characterDataHandler");


    // Open the XML file for reading 
    $fp = @fopen("http://www.abc.com/mytest.xml","r"); 
    if(!$fp)
    {
        return "XML-Server down";               
    }


    // Read the XML file 4KB at a time  
    while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) 
       // Parse each 4KB chunk with the XML parser created above 
       if(xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))==0)
       { 
           // Handle errors in parsing 
           return  "\"XML-Server down\""; 
       } 

    // Close the XML file 
    fclose($fp); 

    // Free up memory used by the XML parser 
    xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
}

function startElementHandler($parser, $tagName, $attrs)
{

}


function endElementHandler($parser, $tagName)
{

}


function characterDataHandler($parser, $data)
{

}

?>
```

Comment: It doesn't answer my present question, but will be kept in mind for future (more complicated) XML parsings. Thank you!